# How to get signaling widget in signal handler for gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtk3, gtkmm

With gtkmm, the signal handlers that I'd like to use for buttons have prototypes that don't accept any arguments. One thing that I'm trying to do is change the cursor to a "clickable" type cursor (not actual name) when it hovers over a  button. I've successfully managed to do this with one button, but that button has a callback made explicitly for itself. I'd like to avoid making functions that do the same thing for every different button, and would prefer to use the same function with a way to determine which button is currently signaling.

I tried to use CssProvider with a stylesheet, but when I use "cursor: pointer;" the CssProvider throws an error.

Here's some reproducible code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder;

// Funciton prototypes
void set_pointer();
void restore_pointer();

/************************
*  User-defined functions
************************/

// Set cursor to pointer when over button
void
set_pointer (void)
{
    Gtk::Button* button_one;
    builder -> get_widget ("button_one", button_one);
    auto window = button_one -> get_window();
    auto cursor = Gdk::Cursor::create (Gdk::HAND2);
    window -> set_cursor (cursor);
}

// Set cursor to default when leaving button
void
restore_pointer (void)
{
    Gtk::Button* button_one;
    builder -> get_widget ("button_one", button_one);
    auto window = button_one -> get_window();
    auto cursor = Gdk::Cursor::create (Gdk::LEFT_PTR);
    window -> set_cursor (cursor);
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // Required. Initialize gtkmm, checks command line arguments, initializes variabes.
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create (argc, argv, "alexeast.sudoku");

    /* Pointers for widgets to be loaded from builder
     *
     */

    // Window pointers
    Gtk::Window* window;

    // Button pointers
    Gtk::Button* button_one;
    Gtk::Button* button_two;
    Gtk::Button* button_three;

    /* Create builder from Glade file. Load necessary widgets.
     *
     */

    // Window widgets
    builder  = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file ("GUI.glade");
    builder -> get_widget ("application_window", window);

    // Button widgets
    builder -> get_widget ("button_one", button_one);
    builder -> get_widget ("button_two", button_two);
    builder -> get_widget ("button_three", button_three);

    /* Connect signals. sigc::ptr_fun() creates a slot/function object/functor. Helps with compatibility
     *
     */

    // Button signals
    button_one  -> signal_enter().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&set_pointer));
    button_one  -> signal_leave().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(&restore_pointer));

    /* CSS for styling
     *
     */

    // Css provider from CSS file in res directory
    auto css_provider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
    css_provider -> load_from_path("styles.css");

    // Add stylesheet to buttons
    button_one -> get_style_context() ->
        add_provider(css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    button_two -> get_style_context() ->
        add_provider(css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    button_three -> get_style_context() ->
        add_provider(css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

    // Add stylesheet to windows
    window -> get_style_context() ->
        add_provider(css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);


    if (window)
        app -> run(*window);

    delete window;

    return 0;
}
```

And the GUI.glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="application_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButtonBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="hexpand">True</property>
        <property name="vexpand">True</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">30</property>
        <property name="layout_style">start</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_one">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button_one</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_two">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button_two</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_three">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button_three</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

And the Makefile:

```
shell   = /bin/sh
cc  = g++
obj = objs
cflags  = `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` -Wall -Werror
objects = main.o

example: $(objects)
    $(cc) -o $@ $(objects) $(cflags)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(cc) -c main.cpp -o $@ $(cflags)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm *.o example
```

Comment: The ideas is that you will use lambas (or other functors) to capture extra state or references needed by the handler, instead of the library having to pass everything and the kitchen sink through as arguments. So, e.g., `button_one -> signal_enter().connect( [=]{ set_pointer(button_one))` and give the called function the extra argument. N.B. better to use references instead of raw pointers for observing and not owning.

Comment: Also, you should not add style providers to individual/multiple widgets in nearly all cases, unless you really have a special case and know what you're doing. Use [add_provider_for_display()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1StyleContext.html#a9e487038629327d4268320b76f979d7f) instead. And that `if (window)` is very pointless since you already dereferenced it earlier... check right away and bail out, or don't check at all.